# inet 3.4.0 omentpp 5.0 cannot find modules

Tags: omnet++, inet

I've recently downloaded latest version of Omnet++, but Inet project keeps showing errors. I've tried deleting it an instaling trough Omnet++ and manualy as import existing project.

Problems tab:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that OpenScenGraph is not installed on your machine. INET's visualization requires those libraries. You should either install them (see the install guide) or you may disable the visualization feature in INET.